# lisp, CLOS: adding a slot to the process class

Tags: process, common-lisp, slots, clos

My program is getting errors with multithreading, so I want to expand the with-lock-grabbed macro to keep track of the stack of locks a process acquires. I want to do this by simply adding a slot to process to store the lock-stack.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to add a slot at runtime without destroying what's already there. ensure-class completely redefines the class. I don't want this, since I don't know what other slots process already has.

How can I add a slot?
In particular, I would like to add these two slots:

```
    (lock-stack :documentation "stores a list of all locks of the process.
Only used for debugging"
    :type list
    :initform nil
    :accessor lock-stack-acc
)
(lock-stack-error-found :documentation "indicates that an error on the locks was already found.
Only used for debugging"
    :type boolean
    :initform nil
    :accessor lock-stack-error-found-acc
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on GoogleGroups linked me to the answer:
https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/msg/7e24e8417cd1b6e6?dmode=source

```
(defun direct-slot-defn->initarg (slot-defn)
  (list :name (slot-definition-name slot-defn)
        :readers (slot-definition-readers slot-defn)
        :writers (slot-definition-writers slot-defn)
        :initform (slot-definition-initform slot-defn)
        :initargs (slot-definition-initargs slot-defn)
        :initfunction (slot-definition-initfunction slot-defn)))

(defun add-slot-to-class (class name &key (initform nil)
                                accessors readers writers
                                initargs
                                (initfunction (constantly nil)))
  (check-type class symbol)
  (let ((new-slots (list (list :name name
                               :readers (union accessors readers)
                               :writers (union writers
                                               (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                                                           (list 'setf
x))
                                                       accessors)
                                               :test #'equal)
                               :initform initform
                               :initargs initargs
                               :initfunction initfunction))))
    (dolist (slot-defn (class-direct-slots (find-class class)))
      (push (direct-slot-defn->initarg slot-defn)
            new-slots))
    (ensure-class class :direct-slots new-slots)))
```

Answer (score 0):

CLOS provides the function `change-class` which provides a way to add slots via inheritance like this:

```
;; clog-web-content is the class provided by the framework
;; it does not provide a constructor, but can be created by a factory function
;; => class mixin does not work

;; my solution:
;; extend the class by inheritance
(defclass cmd-section (clog-web-content)
  ((form :accessor form :type clog-form)
   (label :accessor label :type clog-label)
   (text :accessor text :type clog-form-element))) 

;; change the subtype back to the framework type for later usage
;; of framework functions on this type:
(defmethod create-cmd-section (body)
  (let ((cmd-section (create-web-content body)))
    (change-class cmd-section 'cmd-section)
    (with-slots (form label text)
        cmd-section
      (setf form (create-form cmd-section))
      (setf label (create-label form
                                :content "Enter command"))
      (setf text (create-form-element form :text
                                      :class "w3-input w3-border"
                                      :label label)))
    cmd-section))
```

I assume that this solution might be helpful in other cases as well.