# lisp, CLOS: adding a slot to the lock class

Tags: locking, lisp, common-lisp, clos, ccl

I am trying to add a new slot to the lock class. This is useful because I have a lot of locks in a hierarchy and if I store the parent lock for every lock it becomes easier to detect problems while debugging.

Unfortunately, this apparently can't be done with the ensure-class function. I can  add slots to 'process, but not to 'lock, because it is listed as a built-in-class. See my earlier question here for how to do it for 'process:
[lisp, CLOS: adding a slot to the process class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002816/lisp-clos-adding-a-slot-to-the-process-class)

Do you know how to solve this problem?
If it is not possible, the only alternative I can think of is storing the hierarchical relation of locks in a hash-table, but since some of the locks are created at runtime and in different processes, I would have to add yet another lock just to access the hashtable that stores metadata on the locks.

This strikes me as terribly inefficient. Do you have a better idea?

edit: for clarification, I am using Clozure Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the metaclass using the `:metaclass` class option in a defclass form.

```lisp
CL-USER> (defclass hierarchical-lock (lock)
           ((parent :initarg :parent :reader parent))
           (:metaclass built-in-class))
#<BUILT-IN-CLASS HIERARCHICAL-LOCK>
```

However, even though you can do that and get the class, I'm not sure how you would go about instantiating it.  Trying to use `make-instance` fails:

```lisp
CL-USER> (make-instance 'hierarchical-lock)

; There is no applicable method for the generic function:
;   #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION MAKE-INSTANCE #x30200002676F>
; when called with arguments:
;   (#<BUILT-IN-CLASS HIERARCHICAL-LOCK>)
;    [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

`make-lock` is implemented in [l0-aprims.lisp](http://svn.clozure.com/publicsvn/openmcl/trunk/source/level-0/l0-aprims.lisp) as

```lisp
(defun make-lock (&optional name)
  "Create and return a lock object, which can be used for synchronization
between threads."
  (%make-lock (%make-recursive-lock-ptr) name))
```

You can keep following the implementation of `%make-lock` until you get to the low level implementation details, but it's clear that locks are not obtained the same way that typical CLOS instances are.

In addition to Rainer Joswig's suggestion in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17126509/1281433) that you let the CCL developers know that you would appreciate locks being CLOS objects, you can always use some aggregation and define your own `hierarchical-lock` that has slot for its primitive lock and a slot for parent.  By the magic of generic functions, you can implement methods on the generic functions that work with locks so that your `hierarchical-lock` behaves like a built in lock.  (This presumes that the lock API is defined in terms of generic functions.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subclass that has such a slot.

```
(defclass hierarchical-lock (lock)
  ((parent :initarg :parent :reader parent)))
```

Comment: that doesn't work:

SIMPLE-ERROR
The class #<BUILT-IN-CLASS LOCK> was specified as a
super-class of the class #<STANDARD-CLASS HIERARCHICAL-LOCK>;
but the meta-classes #<STANDARD-CLASS BUILT-IN-CLASS> and
#<STANDARD-CLASS STANDARD-CLASS> are incompatible.

I suppose I could write a fresh class that holds one lock and one reference to the holder of the parent lock. But that would be rather inefficient and I would also have to change the lock grabbing macro as well to extract the lock from the encapsulator.

Comment: @user2339308: please complain to the CCL mailing list that its locks are not CLOS objects. Thus CLOS can't add a slot or subclass it.

Comment: @user2339308 Can you use the `(:metaclass metaclass)` option to [`defclass`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm) to specify that the metaclass should be `built-in-class`?